# How do I obfuscate API calls from Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, gatsby

I am developing an application in Gatsby that allows users to submit their information through a form. The form then submits that information to a private API via fetch. The problem is that this call exposes the API key to the browser, thus allowing anyone to use it for any other API functions.

How do I obfuscate the API call so that it does not expose the API key to the browser?

I imagine it would require me to write a server-side wrapper, but how do you do that with Gatsby?

Comment: keep your keys or variables on .env , on deployement you can add these keys there for example read https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables

Comment: You have two options here: either implement user authentication in which a user "logs in" to your site and therefore gets their own API key that is unique to them that they can use for your backend service or you can disable authentication on that endpoint of your api. If it's something like a contact form I wouldn't bother with authentication but if it's calling an upstream API you should hide your api key on the server side with environment variables. Make the authenticated api call on the user's behalf on the backend and forward the response to the client

Comment: These responses aren't really grasping the problem. I can't keep the API key on the server side if the submit action needs to send the API key to the remote API. The only way I could do that is if I created a server-side wrapper that handled the API call. How do I do that with Gatsby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These responses aren't really grasping the problem. I can't keep the
> API key on the server side if the submit action needs to send the API
> key to the remote API. The only way I could do that is if I created a
> server-side wrapper that handled the API call. How do I do that with
> Gatsby?

Given that scenario I think you have (at least) two options:

- Use serverless functions to proxy the call without having to host a server (where those environment variables would be stored). Depending on your hosting platform you can use [Netlify functions](https://functions.netlify.com/) (for Netlify hosting), [Gatsby functions](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/functions/) (for Gatsby Cloud hosting), [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) (for Amazon-related hosting), [Google Cloud Functions](https://developers.google.com/learn/topics/functions), etc. You can even use them without hosting the project on these platforms.
- Proxy the API calls through a backend-for-frontend, like an Express server, and add the secrets to your Express server

Both approaches rely on the fact that the serverless function/Express server will be used as middleware of those requests, hiding your secrets from the browser.

Comment: Gatsby functions was the key! It's worth noting that this is available even if you don't use the Gatsby Cloud hosting.